# facebook group alike database design and foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Here are my requirements:

1. one user can have many tasks
2. one group can have many task
3. one group can have many users

think of it like a facebook group. Invited user in a group can post more than one status. Each user can create many groups.

so it's my database correct? Do I need to specify FK in bridge key?
[image]

Comment: I've answered your question but I'm wondering if you want to be strict with one of the normal forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design in mysql is correct. If you want to be strict, yes, you do have to enforce integrity using foreign keys in bridge tables. 
If a task can belong to only one group you must remove "Task_Group" and add "group_id" into Task table.

Comment: I doubt the task-group table is necessary, what do you think? one group can have many tasks, but not one task can have many group, my design above which use a bringe seem gave it a many to many relationship.

Comment: In Sql databases you don't have a choice, one-to-many and many-to-many are modeled in the same way, in fact there's a tricky thing into these kind of relations bc you have to control in your code the one-to-many doesn't transform in many-to-many by mistake. It can't be reduced, this table is necessary.

Comment: what if I do not create task-group, just put groud_id inside the task table? and the relationship will be one to many right? one group can have many task? correct?

Comment: Yes, you're right if one task can only belong to only one group. I will edit my answer.

Comment: think of the group as 'hobby', and a user may create many items in hobby group. is that call one to many relationship? if that is the case, I should keep the task_group bridge table.

Comment: confusion again. it's right also to say a task can belong to only one group because although the task name may be the same but the id cannot. That means for example task 'homework' can only be in group 'school' and should not be in the other groups.

Comment: Due to you want an user is able to create groups, it's a one to many relationship. It means you could get rid of the intermediate table without any issue, adding an "user_id" field to group. In that case you connect Groups created by User and it's more accurate. The actual schema means you have a common "Group" table that all users share (like a table administered in a backoffice) and users select from these groups. In your case an User create a Group, so Group must have a user_id field and remove User_Group